# Is there a way to chain additional hours to a Date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to do something like:

```
Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.to_time.+2.hours.to_i
```

When I include the

```
.to_i
```

method I don't get the unix time that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.to_i binds to the 2.hours expression, resulting in a Fixnum (7200). Adding a Fixnum to a Time object gets you another Time object.

Wrap the expression in parens for the desired result:

```
(Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.to_time + 2.hours).to_i
```